# LM3466 current limit - per parallel string or for the current source

Tags: led, driver, parallel, circuit-protection

Is the current limit on the TI LM3466 per parallel string of diodes or is this the maximum for the current source?

Comment: The current rating is per parallel string. See the datasheet [TI LM3466](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3466.pdf), pages 8 and 13

Comment: What if the Current source is say 5A and this exceeds the LM3466 limit of 1.5A and there are 5 sinks each designed for 1A.  Wont the LM3466's overheat from excess voltage drop if the Sinks only add up to 4.9A as the Source rises to try to operate at 5A?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I think the 5x LM3466 ICs will share the 100mA. At 1000 + 20 mA per channel, 480 mA of overhead remains on each IC. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per parallel string. See page 13 for the circuit topology.

[www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3466.pdf](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3466.pdf)

Comment: TY, I'd upvote you if I had enough rep points!

Comment: No worries. You can mark it as answered though

Comment: Page 13 of what?

Comment: The linked datasheet...

Answer (score 0):

looks like 1.5A max on one string, but I probably go about half that for cooling dissipation if you are going to operate it for long periods of time. [image]